# Can WebDriver replace ChromeDriver in order to make Selenium tests work in all browsers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I'm automating my tests using TestNG and Java:

- Can WebDriver replace ChromeDriver in order to make our tests work in all browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Mozilla, Safari, Opera ... ?
- How should we configure the browser so as to use the same code for all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you just new to instantiate a different class derived from RemoteWebDriver depending on the browser you are testing.

e.g.

```
void GetWebDriver(String browserName) {
        if (CHROME.equals(browserName))
            return new ChromeDriver(capability);
        else if (FIREFOX.equals(browserName))
            return new FirefoxDriver(capability);
        else if (EDGE.equals(browserName))
            return new EdgeDriver(capability);
        else if (INTERNET_EXPLORER.equals(browserName))
            return new InternetExplorerDriver(capability);
        else if (OPERA.equals(browserName))
            return  new OperaDriver(capability);
        else if (SAFARI.equals(browserName))
            return  new SafariDriver(capability);
}
```

I suggest you look into this githob project: https://github.com/sebarmeli/Selenium2-Java-QuickStart-Archetype

Specifically, the [WebDriverFactory.java file](https://github.com/sebarmeli/Selenium2-Java-QuickStart-Archetype/blob/master/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java/webdriver/WebDriverFactory.java).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what shall i do in case that in my testsuite i need to declare the driver and also in some test methods inside the function `run(ChromeDriver wd) {//some code }` !

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to run your code in different browsers to use Selenium Grid and RemoteWebDriver. You can find the doc on the following link:

> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Comment: This link is essentially broken.